# How to resolve number not assignable to type Readonly<any> in typescript + vue 3 + vuetify?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using, vite 3 + vue 3 + vuetify 3 (with volar extension and eslint). I am using composition api with script setup mode too.

I have some html code using vuetify's `v-select`. However I am getting an error with the v-model prop when I am trying to assign a ref to it.

This shows the error
[image]

This shows the value portion is just a number
[image]

Does anyone know what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because the **v-model** is two way binding and the Readonly type only allows assignments in the constructor. See the explanation [here](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/typescript/readonly-properties-in-typescript/#:%7E:text=Readonly%20is%20a%20typescript%20keyword,a%20constructor%20of%20the%20class.)

Comment: But I did define the `lawyer_id` value like this `const lawyer_id = ref(-1);`. Is this not right?

Comment: nevermind, I just needed to update all my plugins in node_modules.